# Почему по ссылке не переходит на сайт?

Tags: веб-программирование, qrcode

Имеется qr-код, на нем размещена ссылка на сайт. [http://www.айотделка.рф](http://www.xn--80aalesigv0b.xn--p1ai).
Но проблема в том, что с qr кода не переходит на сайт и когда нажимаешь на ссылку отсканированного qr кода,
в браузер он записывает такую ссылку: [http://www.xn--80aalesigv0b.xn--p1ai.рф/](http://www.xn--80aalesigv0b.xn--p1ai.xn--p1ai/) и выдает ошибку, что не удается найти сайт.
Очень нужна помощь, qr коды уже напечатаны, их не изменить..(
Такие дела на хостинге:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
введите сюда описание изображения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас опечатка в QR-коде: первая буква `a` не русская, а английская. Исправить это никак невозможно, только QR-коды перепечатывать